# How to have xml documentation for the .Net shown in the Microsoft Visual Studio code editor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just installed MS Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop, on a fresh Windows 7 + SP1.
Every time I use a Express edition there's no xml documentation (comments about what a function does or something) shown in the text editor, when I hover the mouse pointer over the code. I'm pretty familiar with what does what, but I like those nice comments.

Aren't those coming with the .Net Framework itself ?
Can this be a limitation in the Express edition of Visual Studio ?
What settings am I missing, or what else I should install to have the comments shown.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Intellisense** settings under:
 Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> c# -> General
and
 Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> c# -> Intellisense

Comment: Tried that and without success. Even unchecked it, then rechecked Intellisense in settings. Also repaired VS installation, with no luck.